# I want to write a bash script to separate characters from special characters?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, files

I am new to bash. I want to write a bash script where I have a file, "file.txt".

I want to cut & paste normal characters to charecters.txt & special characters to special.txt.

Pseudocode

```
#!/bin/bash
touch charecters.txt
touch specialcharecters.txt   
file='file.txt' 
i=1  
while read line; do  
if 
   # the letter is a charecter
then
  # cp that letter to charecters.txt
else
  cp that letter to alphabet.txt
fi
i=$((i+1))  
done < $file
```

How to do this in Bash / shell ?

Comment: That's a relatively complex problem for someone just learning Bash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by special characters you mean non alphanumeric? If so here's what I came up with.
I have a file called `test`
which contains:

```
1234: 2271' 4423'
8901 1234 2569?
1234@ 5678! 9107:
1134 7896 6780
```

If I run `cat test | tr -d '[:alnum:]'`
I get this output:

```
: ' '
  ?
@ ! :
```

If I want to match the alphanumeric symbols I could use this command

```
grep -o '[A-Za-z0-9]*' test
```

I don't think you will need to loop through every line.

Comment: `[a-z]` would match on `aａͣÿ⒜ⓐªᵃₐᴬáàăắằẵẳâấầẫẩǎåǻäᷲꞛǟãȧǡąāảȁȃạặậḁᷓꜳ℀æᷔᴭǽǣ㏂㏟ᷕꜵ℁⅍ꜷ㍳ᷖꜹꜻꜽẚᴀⱥᶏᴁᴂᵆꬱɐᵄɑᷧᵅꬰᶐɒᶛꭤbｂᷨ...yｙ⒴ⓨʸýỳŷẙÿỹẏȳỷỵʏɏƴỿꭚȝz`, but not on `ｚⓩᶻźẑžżẓẕƍᴢƶᵶᶎȥʐᶼʑᶽɀⱬ` as those sort after `z`.

Comment: I guess I did make quite a few assumptions when it came to his content. If the OP posted some test file content I feel like I could've provided a better answer. Thank you for bringing this up Stephane.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`, you could do something like:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN {
    n = split("alpha digit punct space", class)
    RS = ".{1}"; ORS = ""
  }
  {
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) if (RT ~ "^[[:" class[i] ":]]$") {
      print RT > (class[i] ".txt")
      next
    }
    print RT > "other.txt"
  }' < input.txt
```

To sort the characters into `alpha.txt`, `digit.txt`, `punct.txt`, `space.txt`, `other.txt`, based on what class they're considered to be in in the current locale.

Note that despite the name, the `alpha` class is not only about characters in alphabetical scripts. It generally includes characters that constitutes words of human languages even from those scripts that are not alphabetical. In GNU locales, it also includes digits of several numeral systems (to the exception of the English 0123456789 ones which are the only ones matched by the `digit` class). On some other systems, `digit` includes all sorts of digits (though only from *decimal* numeral systems), while `alpha` doesn't. In any case, `alnum` is `alpha`+`digit`. The C standard, and [soon POSIX as well](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1078), go for GNU's approach.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here's a one-liner.

```
cat file.txt  | tee  >(tr -d -C  '[:alpha:]'>char.txt) | tr -d '[:alpha:]'>specialchar.txt
```

This example uses `tee` to duplicate the output into two different process.

First is a `tr` that deletes non-alpha characters (the -C is the "complement" or opposite)  and then writes that output to a filename.

The second `tr` just deletes the alpha characters and sends the rest to another filename.

---

Essentially this is the same as running the whole thing twice like this:

```
cat filename | filter out nonalphas    > char.txt
cat filename | filter out alphas    > specialchar.txt
```

but that's two separate commands and the input might have changed.

Comment: `cat` was used to try and simplify the explanation - remember OP is new to Bash scripting.